# How do I remove Finder tags from all files in a folder and its subfolders?

Tags: macos, finder-tag

How can I remove Finder tags from all files in a given folder and in its subfolders?

Comment: I wish I had an answer, I'm curious as well. If you're handy with the shell then the mdfind command may be part of your solution in the end. Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)'s tag:

```
brew install tag
tag -r /path/*
```

You can combine this with a find command to find specific files/folders + recursive.

```
find . -exec tag -r {} \;  -print
```

Comment: How does one go about using the last line of code on a directory? I don't want to screw up and remove tags from every folder in my system: `find . -exec tag -r /path/ {} \;  -print`. Furthermore, can I just cd to a directory and perform that command?

Comment: @Matt The find command has two components: the path/filter and the action. `find .` will use the current directory that you've cd'd to, or you can use `find /path/to/folder` and specify the path there. No filter is given so every file and folder beneath the given path will match. `-exec …;` will execute the command, replacing `{}` with each matched path. `-print` also prints the matching paths. You can ‘dry run’ the command by removing the ‘exec’ and just using `find . -print` (which is equivalent to `find .`), which will print the list of files matched without doing anything else to them.

Comment: @grg Find is very slow and this command did not remove any tags from my files. Can't we use tag's find files with tags command and then pipe that to xargs? `tag --match '*' --recursive --tags /path/to/folder | xargs -0 -r tags '*' {}`   .I am having trouble with the syntax. Help

Comment: It seems that the tag app doesn't actually remove `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` from the file/folder. It leaves it behind.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `xattr`:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags ~/folder
xattr -dr com.apple.FinderInfo ~/folder
```

If you don't delete the `com.apple.FinderInfo` extended attributes, Finder keeps showing the color labels for tags with colors. If you don't want to keep any extended attributes, you can just run `xattr -cr ~/folder`.

You can use `find -xattrname` or `mdfind` to find files with tags:

```
find ~/folder -xattrname com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
mdfind -onlyin ~/folder kMDItemUserTags=\*
```